# php grid with always visible column titles

Tags: php, grid

I am trying to create a grid in php where I can have columns width resizable and sortable and column titles always visible when I scroll down the grid.

Can anybody recommend a plug-in that can offer this functionality?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: What you want is not really php is more like a javascript plugin like datatables or something similar.

Comment: sure, can you recommend a plug-in?

Comment: This one should do it, datatables.net. But you can search for similars

Comment: when I scroll down this table, the column titles disappear. I need the column titles to stay on the page

Comment: Check this example https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Comment: This does work but is there an example where I can see the column titles and columns are 
 still resizeable?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.